# How to move a step back in foreach loop?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, back

How do i move a step back in a foreach loop?
Say i have something like this:

Do something for the first run. If b == 1, do something again. See code below.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($a as $b) {
  if ($i == 0) {
     //something
  }
  if ($b == '1') {
    $i = 0;
  }
  $i++;
}
```

The problem is, when $b == 1, it is setting $i = 0 but not running the instructions inside.
Any better way to overcome this if it's not possible to step back?

Update:
Thanks guys for the response. Sorry i wan't clear when i typed this.

But I'd managed to achieve what i want by putting the loop in a function and do some conditional checks and pass arguments before calling it.

Comment: would a Do...while loop suit this better?

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve. If you just "step back", the step after will again the one, that steps back and you will end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: Without a specialized iterator (See: http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/) this is not possible in a foreach loop. You'll need a while or for loop for this.

Comment: thanks. didn't realize that ya this would lead to an infinite loop.  ok will note that its not possible to iterate in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is a typo, but you have if ($i = 0) instead of if ($i == 0). Possibly your problem is there?

Perhaps another option would be just doing:

```
if ($b == '1') {
    // do something?
}
```

Final option would be to do a regular for loop and decrement the counter if a condition exists:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($thing); $x++) {
    if($thing[$x] == '1') {
        $x -= 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that $i is getting set to 0 in the loop, it is quite possible it is always 0 (because that is what it is set to before the loop)